# How to select a record from SQL that does not have a certain value

Tags: sql

I have a list of students who have several levels of English to complete. Is there a way to find those students who are doing English I and haven't moved to the next level

```
ID   STUDENTID  NAME     ENGLISHLEVEL   STARTDATE     ENDDATE
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1    001       Eric     English-1      2017-01-01    2018-01-01
 2    002       Brian    English-1      2017-01-01    2017-01-31
 3    002       Brian    English-2      2017-02-01    2017-03-01
 4    003       David    English-1      2017-05-01    2017-06-01
 5    003       David    English-2      2017-06-02    2017-07-03
```

I have a list similar to above for thousands of students and want to know how I can query the table to show me those students who did English-1 but never got started with English-2 or English-3

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your SQL look like at the moment?

Comment: Hint: Use an `outer join` to join the table to itself.

Comment: HAVING a COUNT of 1 would seem to match your requirement?

Comment: @AlexK. Perhaps a student failed it and had to do it again? That would give them 2 English 1 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to itself with an `outer join`. Have the outer joined table check for English2/3, and then filter out any results where there is a match.

```
select
    eng1.*
from
    students_table eng1
    left outer join students_table eng2
        on (
            eng1.STUDENTID=eng2.STUDENTID 
            and eng2.ENGLISHLEVEL in ('English-2', 'English-3')
        )
where
    eng2.STUDENTID is null -- Filter out rows where an eng2 row was found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.STUDENTID = t.STUDENTID and 
                        t1.ENGLISHLEVEL in ('English-2', 'English-3')
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your English levels can be sorted alphabetically:

```
select studentid, name
from t
group by studentid, name
having max(englishlevel) = 'English-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `IN` in your `WHERE` statement to get those students who did English-1

```
SELECT * FROM tblStudents
WHERE ENGLISHLEVEL IN ('English-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "students who are doing English I" mean in data terms in the table in your post?

What does "and havent moved to the next level" mean in data terms in the table?

Do you have a table that contains all possible values of ENGLISHLEVEL?

How are the STARTDATE and ENDDATE columns populated?

If the ENDDATE was only populated once the person has actually completed the training, you could use the NULL value there to look for people that have not completed a training. That might be the way to go here.

If you have a table that defines all possible values of ENGLISHLEVEL, then you can compare the count of distinct ENGLISHLEVEL values with the count of values in the ENGLISHLEVEL table, and that will tell you which students have completed all the courses. You can also do this comparison for each training that way.